# Powershell extract components from file name

Tags: powershell

I'm wracking my brain on updating this script below so that when it echo's out some information it shows something a little neater. I'd like it to show the below. I'll use 000 and Exports as the example but essentially I need it to extract the digits and the "Exports" or "Imports" or whatever is in the * and display it like the below when scanning folders. At the moment the out is just
Clearing C:\Shares\000\Exports

I'd like it to show the below.

Clearing 000 Exports

or Clearing 000 Imports

or Clearing 000 Imports *

etc

Code

```
$baseLocation = "C:\Shares\*\"
$workingDir = "C:\Logs\"
$transcriptFilePath = $workingDir + "SystemScripts\"
$fileDate = Get-Date -format yyyyMMdd
$transcriptFile = $transcriptFilePath+"sCloud-SFT-Files-Cleardown_Transcript"+$fileDate+".txt"
$nDays = (Get-Date).AddDays(-60)
$SiteID = $Site

$pathsExcludeSubfolders = @(
    Get-ChildItem C:\Shares\???\Exports -Directory 
    Get-ChildItem C:\Shares\???\Imports -Directory 
    Get-ChildItem C:\Shares\???\Exports\* -Directory 
    Get-ChildItem C:\Shares\???\Imports\* -Directory 
) |Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName

if (!(Test-Path $transcriptFilePath))
{
    New-Item -Path "C:\Logs\SystemScripts" -ItemType Directory
    
    Start-Transcript -Path $transcriptFile -Append
}
else
{
    Start-Transcript -Path $transcriptFile -Append
}


foreach ($pathExclude in $pathsExcludeSubfolders) {

    #THIS IS WHERE I WANT THE NEW ENTRY

    "`n Clearing $($pathExclude)"
    DeleteItems $pathExclude $nDays $false
}

Stop-Transcript
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As lit already suggested, you can get the platform-specific directory separator from `[System.IO.Path]::DirectorySeparatorChar` and use that to split the path into individual labels:

```
# use $null to swallow the `C:` and `Shares` components
$null,$null,$pathComponents = $pathExclude.Split([System.IO.Path]::DirectorySeparatorChar)

# construct message from the ??? and {Import,Export} folder names
$message = "Clearing $($pathComponents[0,1])"

if ($pathComponents.Length -gt 2) {
  # the path describes one of the sub folders, add the * on the end
  $message += ' *'
}

Write-Host $message

DeleteItems $pathExclude $nDays $false
```

Answer (score 2):

If the second directory in the path is always the one needed, the following code will do that.

```
$pathExcluedSubfolders | ForEach-Object {
    $BaseDir = $_.Split([IO.Path]::DirectorySeparatorChar)[2]
    "`n Clearing $BaseDir"
}
```

After seeing Mathias's answer, I realize that a `ForEach-Object` loop is totally unnecessary.

```
$BaseDir = $pathExcluedSubfolders.Split([IO.Path]::DirectorySeparatorChar)[2]
"`n Clearing $BaseDir"
```

Comment: @Chris, if you believe this to be the best answer, please select the check mark. This is how SO works.